# Better Way to Do Overloaded Functions in C#?

Tags: c#, function, overloading

I have a lot of functions where I take information and populate a class or something. These are willing to accept incomplete information and populate with default values pretty often though.

Here's a crude example.

```
string name;
string address;
string phonenum;

void SaveClass(string a)
{
    SaveClass(a, "UNSET", "UNSET");
}

void SaveClass(string a, string b)
{
    SaveClass(a, b, "UNSET");
}

void SaveClass(string a, string b, string c)
{
    name = a;
    address = b;
    phonenum = c;
}
```

It would be really cool though, if I could do something like this.

```
void SaveClass(string a, optional string b="UNSET", optional string c="UNSET")
{
    name = a;
    address = b;
    phonenum = c;
}
```

This way I could write out all three overloads in one quick go. Is there anything like this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of C# 4, you can do exactly that with *optional parameters*:

```
void SaveClass(string a, string b = "UNSET", string c = "UNSET")
```

Then when calling the method, you can specify *named arguments*:

```
SaveClass("Foo", c: "Some value for C");
```

Or just use positional arguments which are filled in order:

```
SaveClass("Foo", "Some value for B");
```

Named arguments can be used even if you aren't using optional parameters, which can really help if you have many arguments in a method call and it's not clear which is which.

There are restrictions: the default values for optional parameters have to be constants, and the optional parameters have to come at the end of the method signature (aside from `params` parameters) but the restrictions are all there for good reasons.

One thing to note when looking for more documentation - although the features are properly known as *optional parameters* and *named arguments*, many articles (including [some in MSDN itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)) will talk about "optional arguments" and even "named parameters".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Just remove the `optional` part from the parameter.

They're called optional parameters. Here, have a MSDN link: [Optional Parameters.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

You use them like this:

```
void MyFunc(string x, int y = 0)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

Small note: it's C# 4 or later, and all optional values must be constant, as what the compiler does is actually burn them into the compiled code. It's just syntax sugar, really.